# Errorcodes in exception

Tags: c#, exception

I have a proprietary C# library that is basically a wrapper around some C++ code.
The functions it provides look like this:

```
public int func(in params, out params...)
```

The int returned signals success (0), some error code (<0) or some data (>0, e.g. number of bytes successfully read).
Additionally, the library provides a `public EnumErrorCode GetLastError()` function

My task is to write yet another wrapper, that translates each function with error codes to function that throw exceptions

While it's easy to get the returncode into the exception

```
public class MyException : Exception
{
    public int RetVal { get; }
    public MyException(int retVal) : { RetVal = retVal;}
    public MyException(string message, int retVal) : base(message) { RetVal = retVal; }
}
```

used like

```
public void func(int a)
{
    var retVal = api.func(a);
    switch (retVal)
    {
        case 0: return;
        case -1: throw new MyException("same error across all funcs", retVal);
        case -2: throw new MyException("func specific error", retVal);
        default: throw new MyException(retVal);
    }
}
```

I have trouble figuring out right way to also get the EnumErrorCode GetLastError() into the exception
First of all, should I introduce a new property `public EnumErrorCode ErrorCode { get; }`, with EnumErrorCode being defined in the proprietary C# library or should I just store an int?
Secondly, is it ok to call `GetLastError()` while throwing the exception?

```
case -1: throw new MyException("Mayhem!", retVal, GetLastError());
```

Doesn't seem right to make another call into foreign unknown code while throwing. What other possibilities are there?

---

Thanks Fildor for your detailed answer.
I think I´ll mix in that function specific message (provided by the API-documentation) and use a dictionary for the EnumErrorCode mapping in the Create function

```
public interface IMyExceptionFactory
{
    MyException Create(string funcSpecificCodeMsg, int returnCode, int errorCode);
}

// snip
int returnCode = CallToThirdParty();
if (returnCode < 0)
{
    int errorCode = -1;
    try
    {
        errorCode = (int)GetLastError();
    }
    catch (Exception) { }
    switch (returnCode)
    {
        case -1: throw _exceptionFactory.Create("invalid handle", returnCode, errorCode);
        case -2: throw _exceptionFactory.Create("func specific error -2", returnCode, errorCode);
            ...
        default: throw _exceptionFactory.Create("Unknown returnCode", returnCode, errorCode);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: If you need that to be thread-safe, you'd need to make both calls "atomic" to your clients. Also, I'd enclose `GetLastError` with another try/catch just to be safe.

Comment: The thing about the Enum: Do you need/want to hide that 3rd party completely? Then don't use the Enum but just its int representation. Just be aware of what that means to your clients. If you want the convenience of a more "readable" value, you could make a function, that returns the "ToString" of the enum value (for example, of course there are more options).

Comment: Are error codes consistent for all the 3rd party's API? Or are error codes function-specific (= each function has its own set of error codes, where on different functions the same code can have different semantics)? If there is only one set of errorcodes, I'd factor that out and make an exception factory.

Comment: And to finish off: Mind that in your implementation, you ignore positive results. Which would default to throwing `MyException(retVal)`. That doesn't seem right?

Comment: positive results (only few functions can have them) are handled like this: case var _ when retVal >= 0: return retVal;

Comment: Ah, ok. That's not in your example. Maybe you want to add this. In the question text you talk about positive results, that's why that caught my eye.

Comment: error codes are constistent, but return values are not (with -1 being the exception, same meaning across all functions)

Comment: Ah, ok. I beginning to get it. So, 0 = "OK", >0 is some result, which only part of the functions actually _can_ have and -1 = some error, which can be drilled into by calling GetLastError, is that right?

Comment: not quite, 0==OK is true and also the >0 part, but -1 means some internal handle wasn´t initialise properly, across all functions, but -2 for example can have differnt meanings in different functions

Comment: Ok, that adds a little complexity...

Comment: could you please sketch out that exception factory idea a little?

Comment: Will do, just a little busy right now. I hope it's not that time critical...

Comment: Great, and I can wait for a good idea :)

Comment: If the native library declares an enum for the error code then you know a lot about error reasons.  So you only need the MyException(int) constructor and can translate the error code to a descriptive string inside the constructor.  Last statement is just fine, GetLastError is called *before* the exception is thrown, the sooner the better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: To reiterate points from comments:

- If you need that to be thread-safe, you'd need to make both calls "atomic" to your clients.
- I'd enclose `GetLastError` with another try/catch just to be safe.

### Using the 3rd party Enum

This depends on much you want to hide the 3rd party from the clients of your adapter.
If they shouldn't be aware (at least while using your adapter, of course, they would probably *know* there is a 3rd party) of the 3rd party, then you would need to hide the original Enum.

This could be done by making your own "copy" of that Enum. This is possible, but it has serious pitfalls: On each update of the 3rd party, you'd need to check if the enum has changed and change *your code* accordingly. Which *could* lead to breaking changes, even.

What I have done in the past is just using and exposing the integer value and providing a `ErrorCodeToString` function that basically casts the int to the 3rd Party enum and then does a `ToString`. That was enough for my purposes, but of course I don't claim that to be *the* or even *a* "best practice".

### Creating Exceptions

Recap what we have:

- Functions can have return codes of

  - 0 == "ok"
  - >0 (only some of them) == some integer valued result.
  - <0 , where ...

    - '-1' is a common error shared by all functions
    - '-2' and smaller are function-specific errors (different meaning per function)
- On top of negative returnCodes, an errorCode (=> enum) can be retrieved by calling `GetLastError`.

Now, one question would be: Is maintaining an exhausting table of all function-specific returncodes beneficial in addition to just having the ErrorCodeEnum value?

If yes: Things get a little more complicated. But maybe we can set this aside *for now* and focus on the Enum values.

Of course, you wouldn't want to write a custom handling for each and every function. So, what you want is some kind of Exception-Factory.

My assumptions regarding this are:

- You probably want to assign each enum value a different exception message.
- You've already shown a custom `MyException` type, so you'll probably want to use that.

Now, you need to make a design decision. You can use *one* exception type and have it have properties. Or you can derive "child" types from your base exception type.

The latter would make it convenient to group or single out exceptions you want/need to handle versus others you (or the client) want to just "bubble up".

Either way, you'll want to have a an interface like

```
public interface IMyExceptionFactory
{
    MyException Create(int returnCode, int errorCode);
}
```

to use in your adapter (I guess you'll want to inject it), so it can do its magic, and you can throw whatever it gives you.

For example:

```
// snip
int returnCode = CallToThirdParty();
if( returnCode < 0 )
{
    int errorCode = GetLastError();
    throw _exceptionFactory.Create(returnCode, errorCode);
}
```

Inside its implementation, you'll build the appropriate Exception with Message (maybe a derived type) and other properties set to the correct values.

For example you could build a dictionary that lets you lookup messages by errorCodes etc. You could then decide to have that built hardcoded or through a configuration ...